# Mac terminal Chrome Apps.localized

Tags: macos, terminal

For some strange reason the Applications folder for a user login has changed itself.

It seems to have created an Alias for the real Applications folder and then stuck in Chrome Apps.locaslized in the original folder of applications.

This means I can no longer access my applications via the terminal. This is inconvient as I edit the Vhosts file of MAMP this way.

Can anyone shed some light as to how this might have happened and how I can revert it back so that Applications are put back into the applications folder as they should be

I have added an image so u can see what I mean

[image: img 1]

Comment: Via terminal I can't access Applications/MAMP/conf/  .... etc.etc
I therefore can't access these files to setup v-hosts for websites. I am not sure if I have done something in termianl to change the way in which it works. I was wondering if it is an issue someone else has had. Google hasn't given me anything to go on and I don't know if it requires some technical skills like programming to get it fixed

Answer (score 10):

Type in:
cd /Applications

It will take you back to your list of all apps. I don't have an explanation but after playing around with the same issue I got back to my apps folder like that.

Comment: To extend on the answer a bit I used: cd /Applications/

Answer (score 0):

I'm having this same problem and this is the only other instance of it I found on google.  Has anyone else encountered this or found a fix?  After installing MAMP my Applications folder is now at /Applications instead of /Users/[username]/Applications

/Users/[username]/Applications now only contains Chrome Apps.localized

Comment: I am not sure if my previous comment was accepted (I wrote it on phone)
I think I found that I had two instances of an Application folder on my system. I believe I moved the contents out of the original  and into a different one. I copied the Application folder back to the original and delete d the other one. 

I done this via the terminal. 

As a short term fix I created a new account on the machine.

Comment: I have this same issue.. it's like chrome apps took over the applications folder

Comment: To extend on the answer a bit I used: cd /Applications/